# MudBlazor AppBar does not stick at position

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

I have this in my `MainLayout.razor`

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@using System.Security.Claims
@inject HelpDesk.Client.Services.Interfaces.IAuthService AuthService

<MudLayout>
    <MudAppBar Elevation="3" Fixed="true">
        <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Menu" Color="Color.Inherit" Edge="Edge.Start" OnClick="@((e) => DrawerToggle())" />
        <MudText Typo="Typo.h5" Class="ml-3">Autosweep Help Desk</MudText>
        <MudSpacer />
        <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.MoreVert" Color="Color.Inherit" Edge="Edge.End" />
        <AuthorizeView>
            <MudMenu FullWidth="true" ActivationEvent="@MouseEvent.MouseOver">
                <ActivatorContent>
                    <MudChip Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.AccountCircle" Color="Color.Warning">@context.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.GivenName).Value</MudChip>
                </ActivatorContent>
                <ChildContent>
                    <MudMenuItem @onclick="@(() =>  AuthService.Logout())">
                        Logout
                    </MudMenuItem>
                </ChildContent>
            </MudMenu>
        </AuthorizeView>
    </MudAppBar>
    <MudDrawer ClipMode="DrawerClipMode.Docked" @bind-Open="_drawerOpen" Fixed="true" Color="Color.Success" Elevation="1">
        <MudDrawerHeader>
            <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">Prototyping</MudText>
        </MudDrawerHeader>
        <NavMenu />
    </MudDrawer>
    <MudMainContent>
        @Body
    </MudMainContent>
</MudLayout>

@code {
    bool _drawerOpen = true;

    void DrawerToggle()
    {
        _drawerOpen = !_drawerOpen;


    }
}

<MudThemeProvider />
<MudDialogProvider />
<MudSnackbarProvider /
```

but the "MudAppBar" does not stick at the top when I have a body that is long.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Have you the latest version of MudBlazor? Can you check if the class ``mud-appbar-fixed`` is applied to the ``<header>`` and if so, if the position attribute is ``fixed``?

Comment: I have just experienced this.  The MudBlazor.min.css is missing the mud-appbar-fixed-top css.  I don't know why.  I have a previously deployed site that is working, the size of the MudBlazor.min.css is 448993.  The site that is not working, size is 398028.

Comment: I worked around it on my local development PC by reverting from mudblazor 5.1.5 to 5.1.3.  However deploying to Azure using 5.1.5 had no problems, so it is something related to my local PC.

Answer (score 0):

If you have just updated MudBlazor version, clear cache and do a hard reload in your browser.